# Wallets that trade all Cryptocurrencies?

Tags: wallet, altcoin

Been looking around, basically just learning...so much to learn lol. One thing I cant find but...is there a wallet/s that allows trading across all cryptocurrencies? They all seem to be quite restricted in one way or another??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is impossible(as of now), since no wallet are supporting "real time trading" of Crypto to crypto. anyway, if you are looking for a wallet that supports multiple currencies, you can use coinpayments, coinpayments is the nearest answer to your question since you can trade crypto to crypto on Coinpayments (they are using shapeshift to trade altcoins)

Answer (score 2):

Every currency is different, so it would be impossible to support *every* currency, and infeasible even to support many due to the sheer number of coins out there. The closest you can get is keeping the coins in an exchange wallet, which is not super safe long term, but at least convenient for quick trading between the types of coin.

Answer (score 2):

Think of this as a 2 part thing: First is storage of said currencies. The ones you have, and the ones you want to trade for. This will likely result in owning multiple wallets. The other is trading of the crypto.

Exodus, as Willtech stated has been increasing support. They incorporate wallet and trade using APIs with Shapeshift (iirc). MyEtherWallet.com while being online can read/report/transact in ETH and any ERC20 altcoin. The downside is that it's an online wallet and suffered a middleman attack earlier this year.

Beyond that generally speaking [Shapeshift](https://shapeshift.io/#/coins) and [Changelly](https://changelly.com/) are good for variety and ease of use, supporting dozens of crypto currencies each for trading. Binance is an example of a full blown exchange that covers many currencies.

Answer (score 1):

[Exodus](https://www.exodus.io/releases/) seems to support a number of crypto-currencies but I have never tested it.

I am not aware of a wallet that supports all crypto-currencies, there are over one-hundred of them.